# Python dataframe add date for each value in another column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, date, datetime

I have the following Dataframe in Python:

```
   Date        Key
0  2020-01-01  AB
1  2020-01-05  AC
2  2020-01-09  AB
3  2020-01-10  AD
```

Each Date-Key combination is unique. This means that, for example, there is no other (2020-01-01, AB) pair in the Dataframe.
Also, the Dataframe is sorted by Date.

What i want is to fill in the rest of the dates for each key, so that the wanted result should be:

```
   Date        Key
0  2020-01-01  AB
1  2020-01-02  AB
...
30 2020-01-31  AB
31 2020-01-01  AC
...
61 2020-01-31  AC
62 2020-01-01  AD
...
92 2020-01-31  AD
```

or like this:

```
    Date        Key
0   2020-01-01  AB
1   2020-01-01  AC
2   2020-01-01  AD
3   2020-01-02  AB
4   2020-01-02  AC
5   2020-01-02  AD
...
90  2020-01-31  AB
91  2020-01-31  AC
92  2020-01-31  AD
```

Just be aware that i have also other months and years, as well as more keys.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
N = df['key'].eq('AB').sum()
df = df.sort_values('key').groupby('key').head(N)
```

If you can provide your dataframe like this it will be easy to understand and process

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"X1": ["A", "B", "A", "B", "B","C","C","C"],"X2": ['FOO','BAR' ,'FOO1', 'BAR1', 'FOO2','BAR2','FOO3','BAR3']})
```

Comment: i didn't really understand what you mean after the first block of code to be honest

Comment: can you paste your code how you declare your data frame?

Comment: the dataframe is created through filtering, appending and grouping the unique date-key combinations from two other dataframes. these two dataframes are read from a google sheet and queried from a database respectively. thus, there is no declaration of the dataframe. even the two sources use the `pd.DataFrame()` method to make the records of the google sheet/database into a dataframe